# PHP apostrophe escaped breaking links

Tags: php, html, escaping

I was provided with a set of data that represents URL links. Such as: `"doug'sfood.jpg"`.

.

I keep these strings in an array, and then select them randomly to display inserting them into an

```
<img src="doug'sfood.jpg"></img>
```

What Chrome is putting out is:

```
<img src="doug&#39;sfood.jpg"></img>
```

I tried replacing the quotes with a php escaped (`\'`) apostrophe, but this just ended the quote prematurely.

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Missing content type, etc. Cannot really answer without that. My guess is that chrome is correcting it to be valid XML (since special characters need ot be escaped)

Comment: Content type? They are .jpg strings. $arr = array("doug'sFood.jpg"); echo "<img src=\"" . $arr[0] . "\"></img>";

Comment: Content type of the page itself plus doctype/mode (HTML vs. XHTML vs. XML).

Comment: Where does the backslash come from?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: @mario, I believe that's from me trying to use \'

Comment: Chrome is "fixing" your output (cause you've failed to output valid xml). How are your links "broken" if you don't put in the backslash (`\\`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Chrome automatically escapes characters that are not correctly escaped.

Always use:

```
<img src="quote&#39;quote.jpg" alt="" />
```

Instead of:

```
<img src="quote'quote.jpg" alt="" />
```

Certain characters should always be escaped in HTML, for example:

```
' -> &#39;
& -> &#38; or &amp;
```

Check the **htmlspecialchars()** and **urlencode()** functions, example:

```
$string = "quote'quote.jpg";

echo htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES);
// quote&#039;quote.jpg

echo urlencode($string);
// quote%27quote.jpg
```

Comment: Trying this... although this is what's output at the end anyways so its not what I want. The name of the files actually contains an apostrophe...

Comment: If the HTML code refers to `quote&#39;quote.jpg`, the browser actually downloads `quote'quote.jpg`. In order to produce valid HTML always output `quote&#39;quote.jpg`. The browsers converts `&#39;` to `'` while rendering the page.

Comment: This worked and broke things at the same time. That is, it did exactly what it needed too, but I realized the images I was given didn't match the data set in both ways. Some of the data had apostrophes and the opposite in the other location, in both possible cases. I've just removed the apostrophes and the client can deal... thanks.

Comment: Removing the apostrophes is indeed the best and easiest solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, when printing out the filename tags, use [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode) rather than relying on HTML escapes or browser behaviour:

```
foreach ($img as $href) {
    print '<img src="' . urlencode($href) . '" />';        
}
```

This will become `doug%27sfood.jpg` in your example (AKA the correct way to do it). Which hopefully can be located by your webserver.

Comment: Could just be my preference, but [htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities) makes more sense inside html/xhtml/xml tags than `urlencode`. I'd use urlencode when I'm parsing something for headers/redirects.

Comment: Thanks for this too, if you read above you'll see I've just opted to remove the apostrophes and forgo the code.

Comment: @Kevin: Actually: **both**. Browsers do auto-encode non-ascii characters in urls. It's only required really for marshalling `&` and `?` or `#` correctly in QS attributes. But the HTML escaping is likewise a requirement for valid HTML/XHTML. (With most ASCIIish links you get away without both. The edge cases are seldom enough.)